# Set a Browser Cookie to Enable Debug Logging for Guest Users

Tags: force.com-sites, debug

I know that it has a lot of trends created about this topic but none of them worked for me.

So, I opened my site and create the cookie with

```
document.cookie="debug_logs=debug_logs;domain=.force.com";
```

Where i'm suppose to see it? I configured in my "Monitoring -> Debug logs" the guest user. When I try to open the page on my site to get the log and refresh the Logs page, there is nothing... Could someone please help me?

Comment: Are you using a custom domain for the site? If so, you would need to set that cookie to that domain rather than .force.com.

Comment: Also, use the network tab in the Chrome Developer tools to confirm that the cookie gets sent in the GET request to Salesforce.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thank you for your replay, but still not working.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots showing the Chrome request with the cookie to the public site? Also check that the TraceFlag is active for the Sites guest user so the logs will be generated. Maybe check the Debug levels.

Answer (score 1):

To show debug logs of a Public Site:

1. With your browser: navigate to your public site page.
2. Open your browser's DevTools (e.g. F12 for Chrome).
3. Paste `document.cookie="debug_logs=debug_logs;domain=.force.com";` into the *Console*.
   Use `document.cookie="debug_logs=debug_logs;domain=yourCustomDomain.com";` if you have a custom domain.
4. In Salesforce: navigate to Setup -> Environment -> Logs -> Debug Logs
5. Create a debug log for your public User (Site Guest User)
6. Open Developer Console (or other log viewer of your choice)
7. In the top-left menu: open Debug dropdown and disable **Show My Current Logs Only**
8. Click on Logs tab at the bottom-left of the Developer Console.

Now, with these steps done, you will see the requests from the Public Site in the list of logs.